# Sonarqube: Import Jacoco xml report for multimodule

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a multimodule Maven project where the coverage reports are located in another module than the covered Java classes. An import of a not empty xml coverage report (with coverage information) into Sonarqube is successful but shows a coverage of 0.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Checkout following [github project](https://github.com/doubleSlashde/maven-multimodule-coverage) and build it with `mvn clean verify`. After that there exist an aggregated xml report located in `coverage/target/site/jacoco-aggregate-all/jacoco.xml`. You can see coverage data in there and also in the corresponding html-Report.

[image: coverage report]

2. Start sonarqube (current version 8.4.1) with following command and wait a little bit.

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 sonarqube
```

edit: Plugin "JaCoco xml report importer" is already installed in this image.

[image: JaCoco xml report importer is installed]

3. Publish coverage data with following (verbose) command. Importing of report was successful (see log).

```
mvn sonar:sonar -X -Dsonar.projectKey=example -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/site/jacoco-aggregate-all/jacoco.xml

## Log output contains
...
 10:54:28.519 Reading report '<project-path>\maven-multimodule-coverage\coverage\target\site\jacoco-aggregate-all\jacoco.xml'
...
```

4. Browse to `http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=example`. You see coverage of 0.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Sonar report]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that it works if I use an absolute path for the xml report file. So I added

```
<sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${project.basedir}/../coverage/target/site/jacoco-aggregate-all/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
```

to the top maven pom so **each module** points to the same report file. For a deeper nesting of module directories you have to introduce a property `main.basedir` or something.

The main understanding is that you do not provide sonar a coverage report which get mapped to the module classes, but you provide module classes which get mapped to a coverage report.

Comment: it solved my problem absolut path is needed

Comment: This can be found at [Sonarqube docs](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/test-coverage/java-test-coverage/)

Answer (score 0):

Please install `JaCoco xml report importer` plugin on sonarqube instance (you will find it under marketplace just search for `jacoco` there). This plugin will pick up your code coverage and import it to sonarqube. so after installing plugin please use the same command to see result on sonarqube which is

`mvn sonar:sonar -X -Dsonar.projectKey=example -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/site/jacoco-aggregate-all/jacoco.xml`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the given docker image this plugin is already installed. See attached screenshot on the main topic.

Comment: @Rokko_11 could you please share full log of step 3 which you added above to the description?

Comment: I use dockerized maven command to produce [following log](https://pastebin.com/9zKfrdnU).

`docker run -it --rm --name example -v "%CD%":/usr/src/mymaven -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:3.6-jdk-8 mvn sonar:sonar -X -Dsonar.projectKey=example -Dsonar.host.url=http://kubernetes.docker.internal:9000 -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/site/jacoco-aggregate-all/jacoco.xml  | grep -i "jacoco\|sonar|squid" > out-stackoverflow2.log`.

Report gets read on line 640

Comment: sonar log says, coverage was successful imported: https://pastebin.com/CgdQg7TH